# What is topics[0] in Event logs?

Tags: events, keccak

Here's a snapshot from [etherscan.io](https://testnet.etherscan.io/tx/0x15acf440270d1a53744d52f13232b219bb64b674a90a71043128b81be2bc8a69#eventlog)

[image]

Answer (score 19):

topics[0] is the hash of the signature of the event.

[Example from Solidity docs:](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contracts.html#low-level-interface-to-logs)

`keccak256("Deposit(address,bytes32,uint256)")` is the signature of the event:

```
event Deposit(
        address indexed _from,
        bytes32 indexed _id,
        uint _value
    );
```

Comment: this is a `keccak_256` hash right?

Comment: @garg10may Yes, most Solidity docs have now updated to keccak256. It will take time for other places like answers here to be updated: thanks for pointing this one out.

Answer (score 4):

Note when applying this for structs, the pattern is to nest the structs in a similar way. So:

`keccak256("Deposit(address,bytes32,uint256,(bytes32, bytes32))")` is the signature of the event:

```
struct MoreData
{
        bytes32 id1;
        bytes32 id2;
}

event Deposit(
        address indexed _from,
        bytes32 indexed _id,
        uint _value,
        MoreData _moreData
    );
```