# Get the value of ERC20 tokens transferred using the Etherscan API

Tags: transactions, tokens, erc-20, etherscan

I am using [Etherscan API](https://etherscan.io/apis) to get transaction and other details for addresses.

I need to find out no. of tokens transferred between two addresses. For Ex - for Below TxHash I see 1564+ tokens transferred. When I use [this API call](https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=proxy&action=eth_getTransactionByHash&txhash=0x03430ecdf52d37a8d3645fa9b19c072ec367edbd0d4eba3cc1c7f7c5e7dcc7d2&apikey=YourApiKeyToken) I see `from` and `to` address but not token value. [image]

Comment: I am solving same problem, do you get the decision?

Comment: Hello All,  Have you found any solution for the same ? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Here's json result from your api call:

```
{
    jsonrpc: "2.0",
    id: 1,
    result: {
        blockHash: "0x8fe66b0c15a1c1155338bb5628db55f05cfe72d1194931134b4721cd07e9eda7",
        blockNumber: "0x416850",
        from: "0x167a9333bf582556f35bd4d16a7e80e191aa6476",
        gas: "0x13880",
        gasPrice: "0x4e3b29200",
        hash: "0x03430ecdf52d37a8d3645fa9b19c072ec367edbd0d4eba3cc1c7f7c5e7dcc7d2",
        input: "0xa9059cbb0000000000000000000000007a2641bb2fb31ccd33ba5488c886c3bc4714ec6b000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000054ca7578dcf8bb7aa0",
        nonce: "0x15a82",
        to: "0x9a642d6b3368ddc662ca244badf32cda716005bc",
        transactionIndex: "0x2a",
        value: "0x0",
        v: "0x25",
        r: "0x790a06d5773006ecbc719354d966d100470e6267a68d3446ca0ebfd8df4452b5",
        s: "0x4e58eb2997a3c8add1386a47a71ac5bb915a2a53343883ea1ea4d8e69a6be486"
    }
}
```

Please take care of the input field:

- First 4 bytes is method hash:

  ```
  a9059cbb
  ```
- Next 32 bytes is target address:

  ```
  0000000000000000000000007a2641bb2fb31ccd33ba5488c886c3bc4714ec6b
  ```
- Last 32 bytes is value of ERC20 tokens transferred:

  ```
  000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000054ca7578dcf8bb7aa0
  ```

0x54ca7578dcf8bb7aa0 = 1.5641152016500001e+21

Answer (score 2):

Given a `txtid` is possible to retrieve the logs of the transaction via web3 using the `getTransactionReceipt()` [function](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgettransactionreceipt).

Alternatively, you can use this API exposed by etherscan.io: https://etherscan.io/apis#logs

Remember to set the right topic, as mention in this other answer: [What is topics[0] in Event logs?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7835/what-is-topics0-in-event-logs)

Comment: Yes eventually I am trying this, but this would require traversing all transactions of a address and check for that address in all logs.

Comment: Also I am not sure how to find topics, without topics I can't traverse all the logs since they would need pagination which is very ineffective since there are 400k blocks. Still exploring. Was hoping there was some direct way.

Answer (score 0):

@jun.wu,

> x54ca7578dcf8bb7aa0 = 1.5641152016500001e+21

How did you come to this conclusion? Is there any formula or what?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/62572)