# Find topic[0], topic[1], topic[2]

Tags: events, logs

As suggest in [What is topics[0] in Event logs?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7835/what-is-topics0-in-event-logs) I am trying to find out 'Event hash' but it's not matching the output for [below transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x6a987c2566dd65382abe52d2e1ad1078fa0483fb9dc9e9ce57a7b104ce0f947c).

**Input Data**

```
Function: transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) ***

MethodID: 0xa9059cbb
[0]:0000000000000000000000000d2b2fb39b10cd50cab7aa8e834879069ab1a8d4
[1]:0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010e6a06cb00
```

**Event Logs**

```
Topics
[0] 0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef
[1] 0x0000000000000000000000004dc8f417d4eb731d179a0f08b1feaf25216cefd0
[2] 0x0000000000000000000000000d2b2fb39b10cd50cab7aa8e834879069ab1a8d4
```

However when I try to find the `keccak` hash it's showing different hash.

```
  from Crypto.Hash import keccak
  keccak_hash = keccak.new(digest_bits=256)
  keccak_hash.update("transfer(address,uint256)")
  print keccak_hash.hexdigest()

>>a9059cbb2ab09eb219583f4a59a5d0623ade346d962bcd4e46b11da047c9049b
```

Answer (score 14):

```
0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef
```

is exactly sha3 hashing of event signature `Transfer(address,address,uint256)` - an ERC20 token event signature.
Give a try to use [sha3 hashing utility of web3](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-utils.html#sha3) to verify this.
Besides, `topics[1]` and `topics[2]` are indexed params of events, in this case, they're your `from address` value and `to address` value.

Each contract may define a list of different events. However, if the contract is written based on ERC20 standard, it will contain standard events of ERC20 and these events give the same signatures for all contracts and certainly give the same event signature hashing value.

Back to this input:

```
MethodID: 0xa9059cbb
[0]:0000000000000000000000000d2b2fb39b10cd50cab7aa8e834879069ab1a8d4
[1]:0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010e6a06cb00
```

`0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010e6a06cb00` is `logs data` as known as token amount in this transfer. and `0000000000000000000000000d2b2fb39b10cd50cab7aa8e834879069ab1a8d4` is clearly `to address` in this transaction.

Answer (score 9):

`topics[0]` is the hash of the event signature, which in your case is `Transfer(address,address,uint256)` for an ERC20 `Transfer` event.  If you take the [keccak hash](https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/keccak_256.html) of that you can confirm.

You've taken the hash of the `transfer()` function signature. Its first four bytes `a9059cbb` correctly give you the MethodID of the `transfer()` function, but that's something different and not related in any way to the `Transfer` EventID that is `topics[0]`.

Comment: thx, it matches now, but how you got to know the Event signature given that it is not defined and input data only shows the transfer function.

Comment: For ERC20 the event signatures are [defined by the standard](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20-token-standard.md#events). For other event types you need access to the source code to calculate the EventID or to find out what the event means.

Comment: oh ok, so for all contracts the transfer topics will have same hashes. Actually I wanted topic signature so that can filter events bcoz event logs are huge, but still they will be huge bcoz tranfer events would be large in number.

Answer (score 8):

Check

https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/keccak_256.html

provide input Transfer(address,address,uint256)

you will get output ddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef

Comment: Spent the whole morning looking for this. Does web3 have a helper for creating this?