# Difference between method id, event id and ABI signature for event

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, tokens, erc-721, web3js-v1.x

I am confused as to what is the difference between method id, event id and abi signature. I got the abi signature of a token transfer function according to the following web3js function

```
const signature = web3.eth.abi.encodeEventSignature("Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 indexed _tokenId)");
console.log(signature)
```

If I want the method id of the token transfer function of ERC721 tokens should I just consider the value returned from the above code, or it is the first four bytes of the answer returned according to [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/26640/find-topic0-topic1-topic2). Will the same value also be called its event id?

Comment: 1. It's a web3.js function, not a web3j function. 2. You should get rid of the `indexed` parts, the parameter names and the spaces before/after the commas. In other words, you should use `"Transfer(address,address,uint256)"`.

Comment: okay but I still don't know the difference between method id event id and ABI signature

Comment: The method and the event are two different things. Why didn't you post both prototypes here? (i.e., in Solidity; I can understand what the event prototype is but please post the function prototype as well).