# How to decode transaction event topics

Tags: web3js

I want to decode the topics in the event log of all transactions in a contract.

With Etherscan, it seems like I can see the [ABI for each event](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x64d8161b06c089e531a8e822ef611c8a5806217ddecf48d4ff9ec7a78c47d6a5#eventlog).

However, the ABI is not the same for each event. These are associated with an ERC-721 token.

So how do I get the right ABI for each event to decode its topics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few different ways to do this. The simplest way is by taking the abi and address to create a Web3.js Contract object, then use [getPastEvents](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-contract.html#getpastevents) to get a more human readable, pre-decoded version of the events.

Given an ABI, you can determine which event a log maps to by looking at the first topic of the log. The following from [abi->event section](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.5.3/abi-spec.html#events) of the Solidity documentation details the generation of topic 0 and how you can do it yourself:

```
topics[0]: keccak(EVENT_NAME+"("+EVENT_ARGS.map(canonical_type_of).join(",")+")") (canonical_type_of is a function that simply returns the canonical type of a given argument, e.g. for uint indexed foo, it would return uint256). If the event is declared as anonymous the topics[0] is not generated;
```

Comment: Thanks! I think this answer clarifies how event signatures are made in a more simplified way: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7835/what-is-topics0-in-event-logs