# Topic0 of event with enum?

Tags: events, topics

What would be the topic0 of an event with an (or multiple) enums or other non-standard, self-defined Solidity types in its parameters?

Example:

`event EvInventory(bytes32 indexed itemHash,address maker,address taker,uint256 orderSalt,uint256 settleSalt,uint256 intent,uint256 delegateType,uint256 deadline,IERC20Upgradeable currency,bytes dataMask,Market.OrderItem item,Market.SettleDetail detail);`

Comment: If I recall correctly topic0 is the first indexed parameter and it would be `itemHash` in this case.

Comment: Topic0 is the event signature. This should answer: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/73046/75850

Comment: Thanks @0xSanson, that worked!